# Which of these principle ideals is maximal in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

Let $I_1, I_2,$ and $I_3$ be the principle ideals of the $R[x]$ generated by the polynomials $2, x+1, x^2+x+1$ respectively.  Which of the ideals are maximal ideals of $R[x]$ if:

a) $R[x] = \mathbb{Z}$

b) $R[x] = \mathbb{Z_3}$

For b, I got that its only (x+1) because 2 is a unit and the other polynomial is reducible.

I'm pretty confused on a though since its not a field.  I think the way to show this is just from the definition of maximal ideal aka showing that the ideal is properly contained in another ideal, but I'm lost on how to do that and which ones ewould even be maximal.  Here is my attempt:
$I_1 = (2)$, $\mathbb{Z}$\ $2$ is not a field so $I_1$ is not maximal
But I'm really stuck on the two polynomials $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$.  If anyone could please post a full answer I'd really appreciate it.  I need to know this for class tonight, but can't post a bounty until after it starts

Comment: Maybe your two cases are describing what $R$ is? Saying that $R[x] = Z$ doesn't make sense.  I guess you mean , $Z[x]$ and $Z_3[x]$.  So you are confused about which quotients of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are fields? Which polynomial are you stuck on?

Comment: @AreaMan Thats what the problem I was given says, but I assume thats what it means too.  I'm stuck on $x+1$ and $x^2+x+1$.  I think for (2) its well known that $\mathbb{Z}$\2[x] is a field

Comment: $Z_2[X]$ is not a field. What's the inverse to $x$? For the others, consider the ideals $(2, x+1) $ and $(2, x^2 + x + 1)$. (Another way to see that the first one doesn't give a field is to consider the ideal $(2,x)$.)

Comment: @AreaMan These ideals are not the same as the ones generated by just $x+1$ or $x^2+x+1$ so why can I just switch to them?

Comment: They contain those ideals, hence the smaller ideals cannot be maximal